# how to prevent underground drain pipe from clogging

Tags: drainage

I have a hydrant that's buried about 3 feet to avoid problems with freezing. It drains excess water in the line down into the ground about 3 feet down, and I there's a drain pipe that carries the water out to where it can run off.

[image]

[image]

The drain pipe tends to get clogged with gunk. Is there anything recommended to prevent this pipe from clogging? I could put a mesh over it and some gravel around it, but I could still see it getting clogged up because it's just sitting underground surrounded by dirt/silt/clay.

Comment: Yet it appears that the water supply pipe is not, itself, 3 feet in the ground, judging by the elbow heading down to the point where the hydrant screws on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end of the drain pipe should be capped, not open.

The bottom of the drain pipe should be perforated. That's where water goes in, not through a wide open end that plugs with dirt.

The drain pipe should be properly sloped, which requires digging up the whole pipe to correct if it's not.  About a 1% grade (which 1/8" per foot is close enough to at 1:96) - too flat and water doesn't flow, too steep and water does not carry any dirt that filters in. I assume you'll try not doing that to begin with unless it's a terribly short run, and perhaps it is properly sloped already. **If** you do dig it out to correct the slope, the drainage pipe should be below the end of the hydrant, not level with it - so somewhat deeper than this.

The whole area of the bottom of the frost-free hydrant should be drainage rock, and that, at least, is usually detailed in the instructors for those. If the soil is silt/clay, the hole should be dug out 12-18" (300-450 mm) around and below the hose supply pipe end, lined with filter fabric and filled with rock, to 12-18 inches above the hose supply pipe end, with the fabric wrapped over the top of the rock, and around the hose supply pipe and drain pipe where they enter/leave that hole.